# SPRING MVC, inserting ENUM into SQL table & having a drop-down list of ENUM in JSP page

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm working on a basic CRUD project, there is a coupon object which is created by the company, the coupon object has an ENUM parameter, I am trying to do a JSP page with inputs so the user (company) can input all the coupon details & then send it to the server & update the SQL table,

Here is the JSP section that I have so far, CouponType is the ENUM, still missing no idea how to add it:

```
<h1> Create Coupon </h1>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/coupon" method="POST" modelAttribute="coupon">
title<input type="text" name="title"><br>
startDate<input type="date" name="startDate"><br>
endDate<input type="date" name="endDate"><br>
amount<input type="number" name="amount"><br>

message<input type="text" name="message"><br>
price<input type="number" name="price"><br>
image<input type="text" name="image"><br>
<input type="submit" value="add">
</form:form>
```

Here is the CompanyController which creates the Coupon :

```
@PostMapping("/coupon")
public String createNewCoupon(@ModelAttribute Coupon coupon,Model theModel) {
    System.out.println
    ("inside createCoupon company method");
    System.out.println(coupon);
    coupon.setId(0);
    couponService.save(coupon);
    theModel.addAttribute("coupon",coupon);
    System.out.println(coupon);

    return "savedCoupon";
}
```

Here is the Coupon class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="coupon")
public class Coupon {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id")
private long id;
@Column(name="name")
private String title;
@Column(name="startDate")
private String startDate;
@Column(name="endDate")
private String endDate;
@Column(name="amount")
private int amount;    // decrease amount on every customer purchase
@Column(name="couponType")
private CouponType type;
@Column(name="message")
private String message;
@Column(name="price")
private double price;
@Column(name="image")
private String image;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="company_id")
private Company company;

@ManyToMany
private List<Customer> customer;



public Coupon() {

}



public Coupon(long id, String title, String startDate, String endDate, int amount, String message,
        double price, String image) {

    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.amount = amount;

    this.message = message;
    this.price = price;
    this.image = image;
}


public long getId() {
    return id;
}


public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}


public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}


public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}


public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}


public String getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}


public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}


public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
}


public void setAmount(int amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}


public CouponType getType() {
    return type;
}


public void setType(CouponType type) {
    this.type = type;
}


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}


public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}


public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}


public String getImage() {
    return image;
}


public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Coupon [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", startDate=" + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate
            + ", amount=" + amount + ", type=" + ", message=" + message + ", price=" + price + ", image="
            + image + "]";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<select name="coupon-type"> 
    <option value="">Please Choose</option> 
    <% for(int i = 0;i < CouponType.values().length; i++){ %> 
        <option value="<%= CouponType.values()[i] %>" > <%=CouponType.values()[i]%> </option>
    <%}%> 
</select>
```

or the Spring MVC way:

```
<form:select path="com.example.CouponType">
   <form:options/>
</form:select>
```

or with Thymeleaf:

```
<select>
    <option th:each="value : ${T(com.example.demo.ExampleEnum).values()}"
            th:value="${value}"
            th:text="${value}">
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: <h1> Create Coupon </h1>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/coupon" method="POST" modelAttribute="coupon">
title<input type="text" name="title"><br>
startDate<input type="date" name="startDate"><br>
endDate<input type="date" name="endDate"><br>
amount<input type="number" name="amount"><br>
message<input type="text" name="message"><br>
price<input type="number" name="price"><br>
<form:select path="com.example.CouponType">
   <form:options/>
</form:select>
image<input type="text" name="image"><br>
<input type="submit" value="add">
</form:form>

Comment: Have you tried it with this path in the spring mvc solution?```${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/coupontype```

Comment: Florian Kiling, yeah but the Path is the Mapping in the controller which is "/coupon" this method is supposed to create a coupon , to use ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/coupontype I would need to create another method with the mapping /coupontype and then what? I will have two mappings in a controller that each do different things and I need these two things happen in one :\

Comment: maybe its impossible ?

Comment: I just created a spring MVC project and used Thymeleaf. It is possible to display an enum, i update the answer. https://github.com/FloKling/spring-mvc-enum

Comment: Tried adding it but now getting error about the T function...
this problem will kill me Im sure its a small typo somewhere..:\
if you got a minute to look at it I would really appriciate it man
https://github.com/Feuse/CouponPrject/tree/master/CouponProjectCore

Comment: You haven't included the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency

Comment: Ok I did but now I have to configure the html pages to thymleaf & I got no idea how to use thymleaf...dont wanna over hustle you bro Ill keep looking online for tutorials thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1> Create Coupon </h1>
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/company/coupon" method="POST" modelAttribute="coupon">
title<input type="text" name="title"><br>
startDate<input type="date" name="startDate"><br>
endDate<input type="date" name="endDate"><br>
amount<input type="number" name="amount"><br>
message<input type="text" name="message"><br>
price<input type="number" name="price"><br>
<form:select path="com.example.CouponType">
   <form:options/>
</form:select>
image<input type="text" name="image"><br>
<input type="submit" value="add">
</form:form>
```

this is how it looks after I tried to add the  tag inside the existing `<form:form>` tag